# Send Notification to dashbord app When New order is created in Database using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, push-notification, socket.io

Commerce web app. i want to send notification to be showed in  dashboard when new order is created.how can i achieve this using MEAN stack (mongodb express angular and node). can i do this using socket.io. what is procedure to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in looking towards socket.io. Socket.io will allow you to do this very easily.

Frankly, you should be able to read the tutorial linked below and know what you need to do, as notifications are probably the easiest thing you could do with socket.io.

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Basically what you'd want to do is have your clients listen for an event from socket. You'll emit the event from socket when a new order is created.

Comment: i need to know how i will track database records; i mean new orders; i don't want to mingle my socket.io code with already created code